# Installing mariaDB on mac

Tags: php, macos, macports, mariadb

I'm using mac ports to install the mariaDB with the following command:

sudo port install mariadb-server

After the file is installed, I have no idea what's going on next?

I try to find any configuration guidance but I failed, does anybody have some guidance for the next steps after installing from mac ports (like how to start and stop, configure etc)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install db

```
sudo -u _mysql /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysql_install_db
```

Change root password

```
/opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
```

Alternatively you can run:

```
/opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysql_secure_installation'
```

You can start the MariaDB daemon with:

```
cd /opt/local; /opt/local/lib/mariadb/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir='/opt/local/var/db/mariadb'
```

Answer (score 9):

The configuration will generally end up in /opt/local/ somewhere...

You will probably need to

```
$ sudo port load mariadb-server
```

, to start it. And

```
$ sudo port unload mariadb-server
```

, to stop it.

This is just the way the macports stuff usually works - I haven't tried it with mariadb specifically...

I hope this helps a little...

Comment: @RahulPrasad That would likely be because you have not installed macports.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/index_fr.html), It's very easy

⚠️ You should have Homebrew installed

```
 2. $ brew update
 3. $ brew search mariadb
 4. $ brew install mariadb
```

Once installed, you will need to activate it with :

```
$ brew services start mariadb
```

Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Comment: It did not work: after first command "brew update":
there was a message "-bash: brew: command not found".

Comment: @OleksiiKyslytsyn - As I mentioned you should have [brew](https://brew.sh/) installed ! But this error can also occur if you haven't set your path correctly.

Comment: While looking at the questions' labels "php" "macos" "macports" "mariadb", so is there a way to install "brew"("homebrew") via "port"("macports") and then install "MariaDB" via installed "brew"("homebrew") as proposed?